# What does "Sp 12" mean?

Tags: slang

I been listening to [Playaz Club by Rappin 4-Tay](https://youtu.be/2daXghqHgjQ). In the [lyrics at one point he mentions this](http://www.metrolyrics.com/playaz-club-lyrics-rappin-4tay.html):

> I got a hoe named Real de Real She got a buddy named SP 12, now, you know the deal We getz freaky in the studio late night That's why the beats that you hear are comin' real tight

But I don't understand what **SP 12** means. Urban Dictionary was not much help.
So what does it mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about interpretation of song lyrics.

Comment: @Chenmunka: It's a reference to a piece of recording/sampling/percussion equipment. No lyrical interpretation is required to answer the question beyond knowing what an SP-12 is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference is almost certainly to an [E-mu SP-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mu_SP-12)—which Wikipedia refers to as a "sampling drum computer." As the Wikipedia article on the SP-12 notes,

> The name SP-12 stands for sampling percussion at twelve bits, demonstrating the power of the sampler. The E-mu SP-12 is credited with helping usher in the era of digital sampling by being one of the first digital samplers in production, and allowing musicians to take digital sampling in a completely different direction.

Drum samples provide the backing percussion and beats for many songs—rap and otherwise. Rappin 4-Tay credits the SP-12—a vintage machine from 1985–1986—for making "the beats that you hear [come] real tight."

I also suspect that the "hoe named Real de Real" is actually named "Reel-to-Reel," a reference to old-school reel-to-reel audiotape used in recording and sampling.

---

**Followup:** The Wikipedia article confirms my surmises above in a comment in the "Trivia" section of the entry for "E-mu SP-12":

> The Beastie Boys reference the SP-12 in their song "Putting Shame In Your Game" from their 1998 album *Hello Nasty* with the line, "Well I'm the Benihana chef on the SP12." **Rappin 4 Tay in *Players Club* (1994) says "I gotta ho named reel-to-reel, she got a buddy named SP-12, now you know the deal."** Young MC raps in the song *Album Filler* (1991) "It's just me, a mic, and an SP-12."

Comment: This is a good catch!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the lyrics:

> I got a ho named Reel-to-Reel
>   She got a buddy named SP 12, now you know the deal
>   We gets freaky in the studio late night
>   That's why the beats that you hear are coming real tight

Note his ho is named "Reel-to-Reel", not "Real de Real". [Rap Genius](http://genius.com/Rappin-4-tay-playaz-club-lyrics) explains:

> 4-Tay talks about the physical act of making a record. Reel-to-reel is the old fashioned large reel cassette recording style, and the SP-12 was a 1980s drum machine.

Answer (score 0):

I expect her buddy's named after the [SPAS-12 Shotgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchi_SPAS-12), sometimes called SP12:

[image]

(Image courtesy of wikipedia)

Comment: If that is the case why would he be named SPAS 12 is there some logic behind it ?? or it just sounds cool ?

Comment: @Levan I'm guessing this is gangsta rap. I'm not going to listen to find out. I expect this character has been known to wield one, perhaps exclusively. Like calling your buddy Uzi because he's never without one.

Comment: It cloud be the case and thank you so much for the information but there might be another reason I updated the lyrics a bit so it will be more clear. thank you again for the help.

Comment: @Levan You're welcome. Indeed there could. I can't pretend I'm an expert on this particular genre.

Comment: I am going to wait a little while, if it is ok with you, and after that I am going to marks this question as solved.